# Javascript How to get Private variables

Tags: javascript, html, oop, variables, private

In JavaScript, I'm trying to achieve private variables (like in other OOP languages).

Is it possible only through closures OR is there any other way by which we can implement private variables?

Any examples would be really helpful.

Comment: Anything else can be exposed to elements further up-scope. But be careful: variables can be read and overwritten down-scope as well! Whatever you do, don't write `this._privateProperty` and expect it to be safe ;)

Comment: No, there is no other way. But some day: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:private_name_objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a class (function) it's just using "var" vs "this.":

```
function myObject() {
  var myPrivateVariable = 10;
  this.myPublicVariable = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Private members are made by the constructor. Ordinary vars and parameters of the constructor becomes the private members.

```
function Container(param) {
    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;
}
```

This constructor makes three private instance variables: param, secret, and that. They are attached to the object, but they are not accessible to the outside, nor are they accessible to the object's own public methods. They are accessible to private methods. Private methods are inner functions of the constructor.

```
function Container(param) {

    function dec() {
        if (secret > 0) {
            secret -= 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;
}
```

The private method dec examines the secret instance variable. If it is greater than zero, it decrements secret and returns true. Otherwise it returns false. It can be used to make this object limited to three uses.

By convention, we make a private `this` variable (`that`). This is used to make the object available to the private methods. This is a workaround for an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes `this` to be set incorrectly for inner functions.

Private methods cannot be called by public methods. To make private methods useful, we need to introduce a privileged method.

for refrence you can see this http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"By convention, we make a private that variable. This is used to make the object available to the private methods. This is a workaround for an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes this to be set incorrectly for inner functions."*. What error are you talking about?

Comment: actually that paragraph is telling about this variable... before it is that variable

Comment: If you format code as code, then it makes more sense. Howeve, the fact that "inner" functions have their own `this` variable **is not an error** in the specification. It's a consequence of how functions work.

Comment: your correct,and in my sense this was incorrectly used in inner loops that leads to error

Comment: Of course incorrect usage might lead to errors, but then the error is in the code, not in the specification ;) The fact that `typeof null` returns `object`, *that* was an error (or shortsighted decision)  in the spec.

Comment: please edit the where you feel that may lead to confusion that will help me to learn

Comment: I did not understand how "param" is a private member...Generally a private member has "var" in front of it instead of "this" ?

Answer (score 0):

Any variable is known only within the function it is defined in. So, [**Sahil Grover**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2041267/sahil-grover)'s accepted answer pretty much covers the basics, except for a recent addition to the JavaScript specs : the [**`let`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement.

In [**Node.js**](https://nodejs.org/en/) and modern browsers, you can now also do this :

```
function loop(arr) {
    // i IS NOT known here
    // j IS NOT known here

    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        // i IS known here
    };

    // i IS known here
    // j IS NOT known here

    for( let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++ ) {
        // j IS known here
    };

    // i IS known here
    // j IS NOT known here
}
```

`let varName = ...` is known ONLY to the [**block**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) it is in. So, in this case, our variable `j` is only known in the first for loop, but not before and after. If use a `var varName = ...` instead, it is known in the entire function from the moment it is defined onward.

---

Now, let's move beyond the basics.

A strength of JavaScript is that it gives you a lot of freedom with respect to how you define your objects. This, however, is also a weakness, as to this day pretty much everyone has his / her own way of doing OOP in JavaScript.

Most of the JavaScript code I write myself typically uses the following pattern :

```
var keyValueStore = (function() {
    // Private "static" properties go here
    var count = 0; 

    var kvs = function() {
        // Here, you can define private instance properties as "var property = ..."
        // You can also define public instance properties as "this.property = ..."
        count++; 
    };

    kvs.prototype = {
        // Public instance properties can also go here
        ‘data’ : {},
        ‘get’ : function(key) {
            return this.data[key];
        },
        ‘set’ : function(key, value) {
            this.data[key] = value;
        },
        ‘delete’ : function(key) {
            delete this.data[key];
        },
        ‘getLength’ : function() {
            var l = 0;
            for (p in this.data) l++;
            return l;
        }
    };

    return {
        // Public "static" properties go here
        ‘create’ : function() { return new kvs(); },
        ‘count’ : function() { return count; }
    };
})();
```

As illustrated by the comments I put in the code, this pattern allows you to define both "static" properties (properties at the level of a "class") and [**instance**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) properties, and both can be either private or public. And unlike some other patterns I've seen, it does so without making your code very difficult to understand.

#### Usage :

```
kvs = keyValueStore.create();
kvs.set(‘Tom’, “Baker”);
kvs.set(‘Daisy’, “Hostess”);
var profession_of_daisy = kvs.get(‘Daisy’);
kvs.delete(‘Daisy’);
console.log(keyValueStore.count());
```